# Need to edit and rearrange Text points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dxf, format

I have thousands of points currently saved as a Drawing Interchange file that I brought into a QGIS project. Each point has attributes that has one bar of text assigned to it.  I need to add a word above these points and also flip two of the points for every circumstance.  Since there are thousands it would be a real waste of time to do this for each point.

As shown in the picture there are numbers on top and then the names underneath.  I want the Top number and the name to switch places.  After that I need to add the phrase 'N/f' above both number and the name.  I know how to get rid of the other two rows of numbers on the bottom through excel.[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried by bringing it into excel and reattaching it as a table in QGIS but then the text doesnt flip.  I cant seem to get it to switch the position of two points.  They are consecutive if that helps.  Unsure what direction to go.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a screen shot of what it currently looks like and another one of what the desired output should look like?  This will help provide readers more content.

Comment: @artwork21 done.  As stated, I need to flip the top two lines with one another.

Comment: For one you'll have to convert the dxf to a GIS layer like Esri Shapefile that is editable in QGIS, make edits against shapefile version than convert back to dxf.  Are the two lines of text in one point feature or two point features?

Comment: so when loaded (and/or joined) in QGIS, your attribute table has one column per 'text bar' (like name, date, id, ...)?

Comment: @ThingumaBob I added another picture to try and help clarify.  There are points at sets of 5 and there are thousands of the ones shown.  In the 'Text' value is the information that has name/number in it.

Comment: @artwork21 Look at the other picture I added in the question.  It seems that they are one point features.  I have the DXF file brought into QGIS at the moment.

Comment: ah, and each point in a cluster has EITHER name OR number (OR ...) in it's 'text' value? well, the points are drawn in an internal ('_uid' based) order and so is the label of each individual point. to be able to create that clusterwise labeling in your desired order, I think you might need to merge those points or at least all different text values per cluster into one table with one point per former cluster. you can try to fiddle with QGIS label styler but I doubt you reach satisfying results...

Comment: I wanted to let everyone know that I figured it out but my approach was through about 70% AutoCad and 30% QGIS just in case you were wondering (lol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I brought the DXF file into AutoCad and went through my approach to swap the order of text lines.  I brought a shapefile into QGIS and edited it through Excel to say 'N/F' and 'T.A. #' and brought those both back into QGIS, joined them to the existing shapefile, and then converted the file back into ACAD.